# Why do programmers sometimes silently swallow exceptions?

Tags: exception, language-agnostic, swallowed-exceptions

I know it's evil, but I've seen swallowed exceptions in code written by a good programmer. So I'm wondering if this bad practice could have at least one positive point.

In other words, it is bad but why do good programmers, on **rare** occasions, use it?

```
try
{
    //Some code
}
catch(Exception){}
```

Comment: A good programmer would add a comment why he used it. Swallowing an exception without a comment means he is not a good programmer.

Comment: @Sjoerd: Swallowing an exception without a comment means he made a mistake. It doesn't say *anything* in particular about whether or not he's a good programmer. Who knows, context may make the meaning obvious.

Comment: In trying to defend when I swallow exceptions, I realized I should at least put in a comment, I couldn't defend not doing that. :(

Comment: at the very least it should be written to the output window Debug.WriteLine(ex.message);

Comment: or better Trace.WriteLine(exc.Message);

Comment: @Adam Robinson: Every statement has exceptions (pun intended :) ). And even good programmers have bad days.

Comment: I normally comment them: `// Oh well....`

Comment: Man believe me! Those are not the good programmers!

Answer (score 50):

Looking in my own code, I found a place in my logging code where, after failing to write to a file and failing to write to the event log, it swallows the error as there is no place left to report it.  That's one example: there aren't many others.

Comment: +1 Worst case scenario - love it. Similar to "There was an error creating the error report", except... worse? Probably best to at least give the user a warning. Failing to produce a file, failing to produce an error report, and then not warning the user seems like a Customer Support nightmare '~'.

Comment: Yes, I would definitely consider displaying something, if only it wasn't a Windows Service.  Arguably, there are cases where, if you can't log, you should immediately kill the application.  This was not one such case, however.

Comment: @Shadow: That would be a terribly unsafe assumption.  Instead, I assume that I am a moderately competent programmer whose errors will be quickly noted and corrected by good programmers.

Comment: +1. As usual it boils down to what reasonable thing you can do with that exception. Sometimes you just have to swallow it.

Comment: And did you comment there? :)

Comment: What if the user misconfigured logging permissions/path and they should fix it? They wouldn't know now.

Comment: @Tvde1 It would be up to them to notice that there's no log.

Comment: No log could mean a lot of things.

Comment: I would normally expect a service/daemon to log startup and shutdown, so if I don't see a log, then either it's not running or it's not logging. This calls for investigation! Again, for some purposes, a program should shut down immediately if it can't log.

Comment: I wouldn't hide it! Not even in this case. The program was supposed to be able to write there... I don't know which GOOD excuse would allow me to hide that failure. Yes, writing some verbose info to a hidden file is not a big deal. But the program was design (and failed) to write to a file. God know what the user did to break the folder structure where the program was supposed to write! God know what the programmer did (try to write to an empty string file name, etc).

Answer (score 25):

Because sometimes the programmer has more knowledge than the compiler.

E.g. (in some fictional language where division by zero is regarded as an error):

```
try {
    x = 1 / (a*a + 1);
} catch (DivisionByZeroException ex) {
  // Cannot happen as a*a+1 is always positive
}
```

As some languages (e.g. Java) require to catch some/many/all exceptions, the compiler might complain while the programmer knows it is not possible. Sometimes the only way to get the compiler to shut up, is to explicitely swallow the exception.

In languages where the compiler doesn't complain, the empty catch usually is not written at all.

Edit: In practice, I would add an assert(false) in the catch block. If theoretically something cannot happen, it is a very serious problem when it does happen in practice ;)

Edit2: Java only requires to catch checked exceptions. Reworded my statement a bit.

Comment: Java doesn't require you to catch ALL exceptions (only the checked ones), nor are you able to catch all.

Comment: (And assuming it's not a complex number.)

Comment: @Helper Method You still need to catch all the non RuntimeException such as InterruptedException even if your code doesn't have any interrupt call anywhere.

Comment: I would not put the assertion in the `catch` block, but at the start of the function.

Comment: ... and assuming there is no numeric overflow. I think your example shows clearly that the supposedly impossible is often possible, and hence rudimentary exception handling should not be ditched.

Comment: @meriton: A numeric overflow won't result in a DivisionByZeroException or any of its childs. At least not in any well-designed exception tree.

Comment: There are many programming languages where a numeric overflow does not result in an exception at all, but the high bits that don't fit the result datatype are simply discarded. Therefore, you'd actually have to prove that there is no x such that (x*x+1) mod 2^32 = 0, which is decidedly non-trivial...

Comment: @Meriton: It's not that hard to prove for a human: Note that x*x mod 4 = 0 or 1 (and never 2 or 3). So x*x + 1 mod 4 = 1 or 2 (and never 0). It might be hard for a compiler, which was exactly the point I wanted to make.

Comment: You're right. (It's been a while since I needed modulo arithmetic.)

Comment: This is absolutely no excuse. *Especially* when you think or know it can’t happen, swallowing is the *worst* thing you can do. If you swallow an exception that you know can happen, you *may* still be able to figure out what happened. If you swallow one that can’t happen and it happens anyway, you are at a complete loss. And since it can’t happen, doing something about it is completely for free, so swallowing is meaningless at best. I always do something like `throw new AssertionError("This can’t happen", theException);`.

Comment: Well, that's Java.... Maybe you have chosen the best example here. Your code will be no issue in Pascal/Delphi, for example.

Comment: I am downvoting this answer for 2 reasons: (1) It's catching runtime exception, which does not need to be catched or declared = it's useless code. (2) Swallowing exception which developer thinks can never happen is bad practice - such exception should instead be re-thrown as runtime exception - in case the developer was wrong.

Answer (score 21):

I'd argue that a good programmer wouldn't do that without explaining it.

```
try
{
    //Some code
}
catch(Exception e) {
    // Explanation of why the exception is being swallowed.
}
```

I'm very unlikely to just silently swallow the base `Exception` class though, for any reason.  I'd at least try to log the error.

---

Here's a concrete example that I just happened to run across today in my project.  This is part of a JavaScript function that gets an `XMLHttpRequest` supported by the browser.

```
var XMLHttp = null;

if( window.XMLHttpRequest ) {
    try {
        XMLHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch(e) {} // we've already checked that this is safe. 
}
else if( window.ActiveXObject ) {
...
}
```

Since the `try` is wrapped in an `if...else if` that checks the type of object to be created, it's safe to swallow the exception.

Comment: IMHO that's terribly broken. A proper code would either not catch or do something like `catch(e) {throw new AssertionError(e);}` in Java. In practice, there's no difference, but *there no reason to swallow* exceptions here.

Comment: @maaartinus If there's no difference, then there's no reason not to either. Also, it's not a *humble* opinion to say something is terribly broken. Keep your opinions to yourself next time.

Comment: I wasn't *humble*, it was *honest*. And I'm afraid, I'm not going to follow your orders. In case, you found my comment rude, I apologize.

Answer (score 16):

I can only think of two kinds of cases where I've swallowed exceptions.

1. When closing files or database connections. If I get an error on the close, what am I going to do about it? I suppose I really should write out some sort of error message, but if I've already successfully read the data, it seems superfluous. It also seems like a very unlike event to happen.
2. More justified: Inside error handling. If I fail trying to write to the log file, where am I going to write the error that says that I couldn't write an error? In some contexts you could try to write to the screen, but depending on the app, that might be impossible, e.g. a background job with no screen; or just confusing to the user who won't be able to do anything about the error anyway.

Another poster mentioned cases where you know the exception is impossible, or at least, that for it to happen there would have to be major problems with your compiler or operating environment, like it did not add two numbers together correctly, in which case who says the exception is meaningful?

I heartily agree that in these rare cases where it is legitimate, you should include a comment to explain why the exception is irrelevant or impossible. But then, I'd say that anytime you write code that is potentially cryptic, you should include an explanatory comment.

Side note: Why is it that programmers routinely include comments like "x=x+1; // add 1 to x", like duh, I never would have figured that out without the comment, but then throw in really cryptic code with no explanation?

**Addendum four years after my original post**

Of course the REAL reason why even good programmers sometimes swallow exceptions is: "I'm trying to get the basic logic working, I'm not sure what to do if this exception happens, I don't want to mess with it right now, I'm having too much trouble with the normal logic flow but I'll get back to it later." And then they forget to get back to it.

BTW a bad reason I've heard from several people who I generally think are pretty good programmers is: "I don't want to display a cryptic error message to the user. That would just confuse them. Better to silently swallow the error." That's a bad reason because, (a) You could still write something to a log file. And (b) Is a cryptic error message really worse than giving the user the impression that the operation succeeded when it didn't? Now the customer thinks their order is being processed when it really isn't, or they think the ambulance is being dispatched to help their child who is screaming in agony but really the message never went through, etc. Even in the most trivial of cases, a bland post on a forum didn't happen or some such, I would much rather get a cryptic message that at least gives me the idea that something went wrong and if I care I should try again or call somebody, then just say "update complete" when it really isn't.

Comment: +1 for that last paragraph. It amazes me just how many programmers - even brillant ones - fails to understand such an obvious thing.

Comment: If you have to swallow an exception because your computer was unable to add two numbers then you should probably abort the app, shut down, add springs, and bounce that computer right off the table. ;-)

Comment: @BrentRittenhouse And if the computer was unable to add two numbers together correctly, what makes you think it will successfully format an error message, open a connection to a database, and write the message to the log?

Comment: @Jay what? I .. wouldn't... I completely agree. "Why is it that programmers routinely include comments like "x=x+1; // add 1 to x", like duh, I never would have digured that out without the comment, but then throw in really cryptic code with no explanation? is literally one of my biggest pet peeves.

Comment: @BrentRittenhouse Yes. I hate comments that just re-state what the code does. Like my example "add 1 to x". I wish I could say that that was a silly extreme example I made up, but I've seen that exact comment. Like I'm going to say, "Oh!!! So that's what a plus sign does! I forgot that." At least give me a hint what "x" is and why we might want to add 1 to it here.

Answer (score 9):

Because sometime even good programmers make mistakes.

Either that or your opinion of a good programmer isn't the same as some (because a good programmer would have left some reasoning behind as to why the Exception was swallowed rather than something being done with the information).

Comment: It's not always a mistake, though.  Almost always, yes, but not quite always.

Comment: Sometimes the reasoning is simply "I don't care about the exception".

Comment: @Chris: Ok, but when you swallow all exceptions, you don't know what it is you're not caring about.  Depending on the language, it may be something asynchronous and therefore unrelated to the code whose failure you don't mind.

Answer (score 9):

Because something has to be finished for a presentation the boss spontaneously does tomorrow and nothing is worse than the program crashing or showing a nasty error message, while when something is just not working he can always "talk around" that.

After the presentation, no one will improve those "quick fixed" parts of course. ;-)

Comment: If I didn't need it until tomorrow, why would I be bringing it up today?

Answer (score 6):

I believe it's because of Java's checked exceptions. I personally hate them because of this because people tend to think they need exception-handling code everywhere. IMO in 99% of the code you should just be throwing your exception up the stack and not handling it. I'd be happy if the default signature for any new method created had 'throws Exception' in it so that I don't have to deal with exceptions unless I want to.

IMO you only need exception-handling in two places:
 1. For resource cleanup like closing an input stream, database connection or deleting a file.
 2. At the very top of the stack where you catch the exception and either log it or show it to the user.

There are places where you really don't need to do anything in the catch such as handling the InterruptedException from Thread.sleep() and there you should at least have a comment to make it clear that you really don't want anything to happen there.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I use them quite often in exception cleanup code so that I don't mask the original exception.

For example, if your catch handler is trying to rollback a transaction and close a connection before rethowing the exception, there could be several reasons that the rollback/close itself could fail (since you're already in some busted up as a result of the original exception).  So, may want to wrap the clean in a try block with an empty catch handler, basically saying "if something goes wrong in the cleanup, that's sort-of-OK, since we have bigger problems to report"

Comment: You might want to log that the cleanup failed.

Comment: Yes you may, or very well may not. It depends on the nature of your application.

Comment: If you do want to log a failure while handling another failure, it begins to get more than just a little bit tricky.

Comment: Java now has "suppressed exceptions" that provide a better way of indicating that an exception is not the primary problem.

Answer (score 2):

I do it when an exception can't be handled effectively, it shouldn't impact the normal operation of the application, and/or it might represent a transient condition that is known but has little overall impact.

A simple example is logging.  You don't need the app to blow up just because some logging information won't be saved to your backing store.

Another example might be where you have alternative means of handling the situations, like this:

```
private Boolean SomeMethod() {
   Boolean isSuccessful = false;
   try {
      // call API function that throws one of several exceptions on failure.
      isSuccessful = true;
   } catch(Exception) { }

   return isSuccessful;
}
```

In the above example, you may not have a fall back position, but you don't want it to filter up.  This is ok for SHORT methods where the return value is only set to a successful status as the last step in the try block.

Unfortunately there are many calls that will throw exceptions instead of simply returning an error code or false condition in the result.  I've also seen calls that throw more exceptions than what their documentation suggests which is one of the reasons why I'll put a catch all around them.

Comment: +1 It's said that are so many broken APIs around. At our university, people are often told to throw exceptions in places where returning a boolean e.g. would be much more approriate - and not only do they throw exceptions, they throw checked exceptions which often can't be recovered from.

Comment: @Helper Method:  We have a couple rules regarding exceptions.  First, if you can handle it, then it's not an exception.  Second, all of our methods have a success/failure code as the result.  Third, the ONLY time an exception should ever be thrown is if it represents a real system failure.  For example, in a web app, the database server is offline.  That would be okay.

Comment: Why not try{ return true;} catch(Exception e) {return false;} ??

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled on this old thread and was surprised to not see the only justifiable reason why good code would simply swallow exceptions (with or without commenting).

When you write code using libraries and code that is outside your control, there are frequently situations where you need to call a method to get some value that may or not be there, or perform an operation that may not be allowed at a given point in time.  If the method you are calling throws an exception if it cannot return a valid result instead of providing a control-flow alternative, then you are forced to swallow the exception as a signal that the value is not available or the operation cannot be performed.

Good programmers will make every effort to avoid using exception handling to drive control flow except in real failure scenarios that are likely to bubble up to the user as an error.  However, good programmers also extensively reuse libraries and frameworks for efficiency, and understand that rewriting the libraries to provide better alternatives (like TryGetValue patterns), is not always an option.

Comment: If it's the only thing you can do and there are no side effects such as corrupted/inconsistent state, sure. But you don't always know about side effects and bugs in 3rd party code.

Answer (score 1):

Without claiming to be a good programmer, I can at least explain why I sometimes catch and ignore. There are times when what I'm working on has to deal with an exception to compile, but is not the appropriate place to actually handle the exception. For instance, I was recently working in a program which parses a good deal of XML as one of its tasks. The actual XML parser opened a file, which generated an exception. The XML parser was not the best place to generate a dialog informing the user of bad file choice, though. Rather than get sidetracked with throwing the exception to the right place and handling it there, I silently caught the exception, leaving a comment and TODO (which my IDE tracks for me). This allowed me to compile and test without actually handling the exception. Sometimes, I will forget to take care of the TODO immediately, and the swallowed exception sticks around for a while.

I know this is not the best programming practice, and I certainly am not an expert programmer, but I think this is an example of why someone would want to do this.

Comment: Temporarily swallowing exceptions during development is a different matter than releasing code that swallows.

Comment: Yeah, in this case, they're catching and ignoring, not catch-and-rethrow.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this when there some is some piece of code where regardless of it failing I want the program to continue. For example I've opened an optional log file and regardless of why it failed to work I want to continue the execution of the program.

Even so though, it's not good code as you can get exceptions like out of memory exceptions that ignoring makes no sense at all so even though i've done it, it's still not the best idea and I wouldn't admit to doing it in public. (oops...)

I've done it on programs that are intended to be run once to convert some data or something just to shut the compiler up. That's an entirely different situation to any form of production code though.

Basically there is no good reason for doing this other than lazyness.

Answer (score 1):

we use exceptions for runtime errs. because of users and sometimes requirements and such things that occurs when there is a problem. and if we want to show the error to the user we might raise exceptions. 
eg:-

1. when the software is running there might be a requirement err and it can be solved by the
   program itself. so in such cases, the programmer chose to use try statements and there may be a hardware requirement that can't be solved by the software in such cases the programmer chooses the path of raising an exception to alert the user.

and there are many cases that we choose the path of raising an exception or handling exceptions the situation matter.

Answer (score 0):

at the very least write it to the output window

```
try
{ }
catch (exception ex)
{
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Writeline(" exception in method so and so : " ex.message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about when performing a progress-control update?  I've updated the state variables used by a control's drawing routine, so the next time the control is drawn it will show the proper state.  I then perform:

```
  Try
    MyControl.BeginInvoke(MyControlUpdateDelegate);
  Catch Ex as Exception
  End Try
```

If the control still exists, it will update.  If it gets disposed, I won't care whether it gets updated or not.  If the control isn't disposed, but can't be updated for some other reason, I still won't really care whether it gets updated or not because I'm not apt to be able to do anything sensible about it anyway.

Note that I could add "If Not MyControl.IsDisposed Then..." but that would just add work to the common case, and wouldn't prevent the exception from occurring if the control gets disposed during the BeginInvoke.

Comment: This would be better if you caught the specific exception that is expected.

Comment: @Steven Sudit: It would most likely be an ObjectDisposedException, but I don't know that there wouldn't be some variation on hide, minimize, etc. which wouldn't dispose the object but would prevent BeginInvoke from working.  It seems more likely that I'd get an unanticipated exception from a situation where stuff should keep working, than from one where everything should die.

Comment: That's an entirely valid point, and may well win on practicality.  The downside is that some other exception may occur, and you'd lose it.  That's why logging this at the warning level may be a good idea.

Comment: If some human were actually going to look at logs, I suppose that generating a log when something other than an ObjectDisposed exception occurred might be good (an ObjectDisposed exception is sufficiently expected and unavoidable as to not be worth logging) simply to get a list of what other exceptions might rarely occur.  If an application is going to be used by non-technical end-users, though, what would be accomplished by logging such exceptions in the release build?

Comment: @supercat: If you want a reply, please prefix my name the way I just did with yours.  Anyhow, you never log for purely non-technical users.  And when you log *due* to an exception, you always log the exception itself, including its inner exception chain.  The easiest way is `ToString`.

Comment: @Steven Sudit: I try to prefix names (see above) but sometimes I forget.  Suppose that one day when a user is running my application they close a control at just the right time to cause the BeginInvoke to hit some other exception.  Should I throw a pop-up that says "Don't panic, but please convey the following to the author of the program somehow" or what?

Comment: Ideally, we would know all of the exceptions that could be caused by premature cancellation and catch them all.  But there's no guarantee of this.  Instead, when we catch the rest of the exceptions, we could throw them as inner exceptions, where the top-level one has an appropriate message, such as "Unable to complete task due to interruption".

Comment: @Steven Sudit: The situation I'm concerned about is when an observer window is closed for an object which exists for reasons other than display in that window.  The object being observed should continue to exist and do whatever it was doing without regard for whether or not a particular observer window is open.  Closing the window shouldn't interrupt the task at hand.

Comment: Maybe the solution doesn't involve ignoring exceptions, though.

Comment: @Steven Sudit: What would it involve doing?  The desired semantics are "if this control works, update it; if not, it's probably not worth updating".

Comment: I was hinting at the idea that the solution would to avoid the original problem.  This is essentially just a race condition.

Comment: @Steven Sudit: It is indeed a race condition, but one which so far as I know has no solution other than to swallow the exception (and I have no idea how to be certain of what exceptions I might get as a result of the race).  I can't guarantee that anything that disposes of my viewer control will acquire any particular lock before doing so, and I can't do my BeginInvoke from the control's thread because the only non-blocking way to sequence code for a control's thread is to use BeginInvoke.

Comment: I'm thinking that, rather that there really must be some way to tell if the control is still alive, even if it means doing some sort of synchronization.  For example, the invoke could be wrapped in a lock, while the handler that closes that window could likewise wait on that lock.  This way, the window only gets closed *after* the message goes through.  Am I completely nuts?

Comment: @Steven Sudit: For that to work, it would be necessary to have control over anything that might dispose the window.  I suppose I could override the Dispose method and replace it with one that acquires a lock, sets my own dontUseAnymore flag, releases the lock, and then calls the old Dispose, but that seems worse than simply swallowing exceptions from BeginInvoke.  Of course, a TryBeginInvoke function would have avoided the whole problem.

Comment: @supercat: Oh, I wasn't suggesting it should set any additional flags (other than whatever it uses to tell it was already disposed).  My point is that `Dispose` is run exactly once, so serializing it with regard to that delegate sounds like the *correct* way to avoid the problem.  Having said that, yes, it does sound difficult to retrofit the infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the nature of the applications I write, virtually every exception I catch needs to be logged to a file.

Exceptions should never be eaten without any kind of rethrow, logging, or even a comment explaining why the exception was silently eaten.  In my earlier years I would often eat exceptions if I knew that I was the only person working on the code.  Of course when it came time to revisit the code I would forget what that exception really meant, and I'd have to retest everything to figure it out again.